# How to display the name of the wilaya and the name of the municipality on the map instead of displaying their id?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, leaflet

How to display the name of the wilaya and the name of the municipality on the map instead of displaying their id?

The code below displays the wilaya id and the commune id instead of displaying the wilaya name and the commune name.

How to solve this problem

```
#models.py wilaya

class Wilaya(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)``
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
    matricule=models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,null=False)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#models.py commune

class Commune(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
    wilaya=models.ForeignKey(Wilaya,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


#models.py even

class Even(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Even')
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    wilaya=models.ForeignKey(Wilaya,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True,blank=True
    commune=models.ForeignKey(Wilaya,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True,blank=True
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True,)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#map.html

var even = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'even' %}", {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: "/static/img/icons/red.png",
            iconSize: [28, 32],
            iconAnchor: [12, 28],
            popupAnchor: [0, -25]
        }),
        title: feature.properties.name, 
        riseOnHover: true
      });
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var content = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table- 
            condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Name</th><td>" + feature.properties.name + "</td> 
            </tr>" + "<tr><th>Date</th><td>" + feature.properties.date + "</td></tr> 
            </th></table>" + "<details><summary>" + "See more details"+"</summary> 
            <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + " 
            </td></tr>" + "<tr><th>Commune</th><td>" + feature.properties.commune + " 
            </td></tr>" + "<tr><th>Wilaya</th><td>" + feature.properties.wilaya + " 
            </td></tr>" + "</table></details>";
        layer.on({
            click: function (e) {
                layer.bindPopup(content).openPopup(e.latlng);   
            }
        });
      }
      }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a @property method like this:

```
@property
def wilaya_label(self):
    return self.wilaya.name
```

Now you can access like this:

```
feature.properties.wilaya_label
```

or

```
{{ object.wilaya_label }}
```

Comment: The result for this solution is: undefined.

Comment: I would like to point out that in the Wilaya object the name of the wilaya is displayed normally. The problem arises in the Even object where the wilya field is defined as follows:
wilaya = models.ForeignKey (Wilaya, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, null = True).

Comment: So, I think the solution is to recover the name of the wilaya according to its id.

Comment: if you try the second one append quotes like this "{{ object.wilaya_label }}"

Comment: how to use the sencod one in onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

Comment: I replaced feature.properties.wilaya by {object.wilaya_label}} the result is NaN

Comment: dont forget "" and {{ }}

Comment: I replaced feature.properties.wilaya by "{{object.wilaya_label}}"  no display . is empty